# Error trying to execute sql statement between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

The SQL:

```
dim sql
sSql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table] WHERE [sent] = 1 and datesent between '" & dStartDate & "' and '"  & dFinishDate & "'"
response.write(sSql)
set oRs = oConn.execute(sSql)
```

When i execute this sql in sql server 2008 it works fine.
However, when i execute it within my application i get error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07'

The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted
in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

Is there something different i have to do in the application? thanks

Comment: Show your ASP code executing this SQL.

Comment: Use query parameters to avoid type errors and SQL injection...

Comment: Have you tried using yyyyMMdd dates? This usually avoids any locale issues. Your query then becomes ... between '20120101' and '20120127'. You are probably getting an error because it's assuming dd/MM/yyyy and month 27 is undefined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Table] 
WHERE 
    [sent] = 1 
and datesent between CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/2012', 101) and CONVERT(datetime, '01/27/2012', 101)
```

**OR**

Your column `datesent` is not `DATETIME` datatype

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using ISO format dates?

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table]  
WHERE [sent] = 1 and datesent between '20120101' and '20120127'
```

(Strictly speaking an [ISO 8601 date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for sql server is `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss[.mmm]`)

Side Note: always use ISO format dates when you output to text (or have literals); that way they can be read unambiguously on all systems).

[SQL Server ISO 8601 Format Dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Slashed format (and dashed) doesn't work if you're targetting a `datetime`. This produces an error:`set language british;select CONVERT(datetime,'2012/01/27')`. If only specifying a date, omit separators completely. All works without issue against a `datetime2`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your datetime setting.

```
set dateformat mdy
select CAST('01/27/2012' as datetime)
set dateformat dmy
select CAST('01/27/2012' as datetime) --> Exception
```

You can display the current setting with:

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the ISO-formats 'YYYYMMDD' for your dates, as this will always be parsed correctly by SQL Server, regardless of localization setting.

Comment: Ahem. `set language british;select CONVERT(datetime,'2012-01-27')` produces an error in SQL Server.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I have for a long time only accepted without the dashes, but recently started working at a new place where they insisted that WITH dashes was correct. Until now, I've been unable to come up with a counter-example, so I'd modified my stance to accept both variants.

Comment: set language british;select CONVERT(datetime,'20120127') works just fine locally - it's those pesky dash[es] ;-)